# data not uploading properly due to >

Tags: html, special-characters

Is there a way that i can escape `>`, I have a combo box which has an option below. I tried replacing `>` with `&gt;` but it's still not uploading properly.

```
<select name="Category3" id="Category3">
<option value="Request |Running > 1 hour">Request |Running > 1 hour</option>
```

What it should upload is just **Request |Running > 1 hour**

but what is being uploaded is: **Request |Running > 1 hour 1 hour' />**

i dont know where its getting the other **1 hour' />**

i tried removing the `>` and it just uploaded **Request |Running 1 hour** without the excess **1 hour' />** but i need it for consistency

here is the php code that im using to upload to db

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    require 'include/DB_Open.php';

    $Category3 = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['Category3']);

    if (isset($ABC))    
    {
    $sql="INSERT into XXX category_2
          VALUES ('".$Category3."')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

here is my code for retrieving the data

```
$sql="SELECT category_2
        FROM XXX
        WHERE resolved_date BETWEEN '" . $date . "' AND '" . $date1 . "'
        ORDER BY resolved_date";
$myData = mysql_query($sql);

//to count if there are any results
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($myData);

if($numrow == 0)
{
    echo "No results found.";
}
else
{
    echo "$numrow";
}
{

echo "<table width='auto' cellpadding='1px' cellspacing='0px' border=1 align='center'>
<tr>
<th align='center'><strong>Category 3</strong></th>
</tr>"; 

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) 
{
echo "<form action='retrieve.php' method='post'>";

echo"<tr>"; 
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['category_2'] . "<input type=hidden name=category_2 value=" . $info['category_2'] . "' /> </td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "</form>";
}
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You tried `&gt` or `&gt;` ?

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting 'content' like this value attribute and the option text.

Comment: try to parse the html > should be &#60; or &lt; take a look to http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

Comment: @Mike, yeah...sorry i mean &gt;....i have tried &#60; as well to no avail

Comment: Use integers for the option values. This way you can allways change the Text of the option but the internal value remains the same. The way you're doing it now makes you change a lot later on in your backend code if some value changes. Also character encoding should be no problem when using numbers as option values. EDIT: After the form was submitted you should translate the option value into the desired text either hard-coded or via some config file or database table containing the translation data.

Comment: @user2579439 can you post the exact code that you are outputting to the browser? What you have above is using `>` instead of `&gt;`.

Comment: What do you see if you look at the HTML in "View Source" and the DOM inspector? Do you see the extra text in the value attribute there?

Comment: @Mike `<select name="Category3" id="Category3">
<option value="Request |Running &gt; 1 hour">Request |Running > 1 hour</option>` here it is

Comment: @user2579439 On another note, why, oh why would you disable error_reporting?

Comment: @Barmar yes im seeing the extra **1 hour' />** when i echo the result

Comment: We need to see the code that outputs the option, not the code that puts it into the DB.

Comment: @Barmar i tried to echo again and here is the result...`INSERT into XXX (category_2) VALUES ('Request |Running > 1 hour')`...sorry im not seeing the extra **1 hour' />** when i upload it but when i retrieved it

Comment: LIke I said, we need to see the code that's creating the web page, not the code that's inserting into the DB.

Comment: @Barmar pls see updates above...

Comment: @user2579439 That's not even the right code. I don't see `<option` anywhere nor do I see `&gt;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you're displaying text that might include special HTML characters, you should use `htmlentities()` to encode it properly, so these characters don't cause the HTML to be misparsed (or worse, allow script injection).

```
$cat2 = htmlentities($info['category_2']);
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $cat2 . "<input type='hidden' name='category_2[]' value='" . $cat2 . "' /> </td>";
```

You also were missing the `'` after `value=`. I've added that (and quotes around all the other attributes).

Since you're creating multiple inputs with the same name, you need to give them an array-style name so that the server script can get all the values. `$_POST['category_2']` will be an array.

Comment: i tried what u suggest but im getting this `Notice: Undefined variable: info in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\retrieve.php on line 32` which refers to this `$cat2 = htmlentities($info['category_2']);` and when i try to retrieve im not getting anything from the affected column...

Comment: I don't see how that variable can be undefined, since it's assigned 4 lines earlier in the `while($info = ...)` line.

Comment: I suspect you put `$cat2 = ...` in the wrong place. It should be inside the `while` loop, right before that `echo` line that prints the hidden category. But I'm not sure how you expect that code to work, since you're creating multiple elements with the same name in a loop. You need to give them an array name like `name='category_2[]'`.

Comment: yeah ur right...it was misplaced...i followed what u suggested and it works brilliant...thanks for the assist and for explaining things out...

Comment: I'm voting you up for the beard. It's a little pixelated, but still a good quality beard.